# Converting Mysql to Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I was told to stop using MySQL and now learning MySQLi. However I ran into a problem using fetch array and don't know what I did wrong.

```
//Connect to db
include "mysqli_connect.php";

// Construct our join query
$sql = "SELECT userID, username, lastlogin FROM users";

//Crate results
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

---

Messages I see:

- [Connection Successful] Host info: db413417616.db.1and1.com via
  TCP/IP
- Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Couldn't fetch
  mysqli in /homepages/9/d413002686/htdocs/maintenance/testsession.php
  on line 9
- Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be
  mysqli_result, null given in
  /homepages/9/d413002686/htdocs/maintenance/testsession.php on line 12
- Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be
  mysqli_result, null given in
  /homepages/9/d413002686/htdocs/maintenance/testsession.php on line 15
- Warning: mysqli_close() [function.mysqli-close]: Couldn't fetch
  mysqli in /homepages/9/d413002686/htdocs/maintenance/testsession.php
  on line 18 ()

I used this to for mysqli_connect.php: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

```
<?php
// $link (host, username, password, database)
$link = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');

//If connection is successful, otherwise show error message. 
if (!$link) {
    die('[Connect Fail] Error: (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// Echo success message
echo '[Connection Successful] Host info: ' . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . "\n";

// Close the link
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Are you seeing an error, or is `$row` just not what you think it should be? Can you show the contents of `mysqli_connect.php` (with credentials removed)?

Comment: You have not tested for failure of the query.  `if (!$result) echo mysqli_error();`

Comment: +1 for doing the right thing :)

Comment: @grossvogel I used http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: @taeja87: It looks to me like the problem is inside that include file. We can't help you with *your* code unless you show it to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in your include file should be removed:

```
// Close the link
mysqli_close($link);
```

You're closing `$link`, a.k.a. your connection to the database, and then trying to use it in your query. You only want to close it when you're all done with it.